# C# DataTable: ImportRow(DataRow) vs. Rows.Add(DataRow.ItemArray)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I have two `DataTable` with the same schema:

```
DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
DataTable t2 = t1.Clone();
```

If I want to add a new `DataRow` to `t1`:

```
DataRow row=t1.NewRow();
t1.Rows.Add(t1);
```

I cannot use `t1.ImportRow(row);` since after been created, `row` is in a detached state, and therefore it would be ignored by the `ImportRow` method (see [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx)).

Now I want to copy `row` into `t2`: I know that a `DataRow` object can be contained only in one `DataTable`, therefore one needs to create a copy, to do it one can use two methods:

```
t1.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

or

```
t1.ImportRow(row);
```

**My question is: are `t1.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);` and `t1.ImportRow(row);` equivalent? Are all my assumptions correct?**

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the code and it looks like `t1.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);`
would be a little less complex. Anyway the methods are not equivalent technicaly.

Comment: What do you mean with "not equivalent technically"? Do they have different side effects or results?

Comment: @WoDoSc they actually have different code, the Import method does additional checks etc. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,2954 http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,2539